# position absolute и скролл родителя

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго всем времени суток, столкнулся с неожиданной для себя проблемой, хотелось бы понять причины такого поведения.

На сайте есть бутстрап табы,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.nav-tabs {
margin-bottom: 19px;
border: 0;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow-y: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;}
```

как можно увидеть табы прокручиваются при большом количестве контента, и в связи с этим я захотел добавить блюр по правому краю

```
.nav-tabs:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 10%;
right: 0;
height: 80px;
top: -33px;
z-index: 2;
background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 1%, transparent 10%,#ffffff 100%);}
```

но неожиданно данный элемент стал прокручиваться вместе с остальным содержимым табов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите пожалуйста, что я упускаю? с css увы знаком не столь сильно как хотелось бы

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы создаёте контейнер `nav-tabs` и делаете его релативным вы кладете в него абсолютный `before` элемент. который начинает отсчитывается от родителя (так как родитель релативный)! Далее происходит сдвиг родителя (прокручивание), но так как `before` отсчитывается от него, то он сдвигается на такое же расстояние `right: 0`.

Для решения проблемы можно сделать так:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="nav-tabs">
        //вывод элементов
    </div>
    //before....
</div>
```

Т.е делаете еще один контейнер со 100% шириной и релативным и ему присваиваете элемент `before`, а прокручивание делаете так же блоку `nav-tabs`

Comment: т.е прокручивание родителя на самом деле является сдвигом родителя?

Comment: @Тэрциус скорее всего да! я не знаю как у Вас реализован скролл по горизонтали! чтобы в зависимости от контента появлялся скролл. Но проще всего просто вытащить before на уровень выше и прижать к правому краю и всё!